# Sorting array by time and date using date-fns

Tags: reactjs

I have an array with blog posts that I wanted sorted by newest entry. I'm able to map through the array just fine but I want the newest entry located at the very top of the page and right now it's going to the bottom. If I sort the array by time/date I know it will work but having issues getting it to sort.

```
const BlogTopic = [
  {
    title: "First Post",
    message: "test",
    author: "Dagger",
    date: format(new Date(), "2/13 2:09a"),
  },
  {
    title: "Second Post",
    message: "test",
    author: "Dagger",
    date: format(new Date(), "2/13 3:48a"),
  },
];
```

I'm also using a `form` to add new entries and it's saving all the above information and adding a new object at the end of the array. When it comes to adding a date I'm using this format.

```
date: format(new Date(), "M/dd h:mma"),
```

And this is my code for sorting the array.

```
const [topic, setTopic] = useState(BlogTopic);

{topic
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))
  .map(({ title, author, date }, index) => (
     <tr>
       <td className="blog__topic">
         <a href="/">{title}</a>
       </td>
       <td>{author}</td>
       <td>{date}</td>
     </tr>
   ))}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my full state. Any ideas for how I can change the `2/17 3:48a` below so it automatically takes the current date and time?

```
  const [title, setTitle] = useState();

  const addTopic = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTopic([
      ...topic,
      {
        title: title,
        message,
        author: "Dagger",
        count: 1,
        date: parse("2/17 3:48a", "M/dd h:mma", new Date()),
      },
    ]);
    setTitle("");
  };
```

Comment: Try reversing the parameters in the sort function: `sort((b, a) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))`. Alternatively, you can reverse the substraction instead.

Comment: @carlosV2 thank you for the response. I tried that as well and it didn't work.

Comment: Wait, I think you are misusing the `format` method from `date-fns`. This method is used to fromat a Date object (first parameter) into a string of a given format (second string). I think what you want to do is to use `parse` instead. For example: `parse("2/13 3:48a", "M/dd h:mma", new Date())`. If you replace your dates with this, it should sort them correctly. You won't even need to wrap them in `new Date()` as they will already be a Date object. It is on the markup when you want to use format: `format(date, "M/dd h:mma")`

Comment: @carlosV2 You're right it is the way I'm formatting my date. I did what you suggested and I'm getting errors saying `parse is not defined`. Unless I misunderstood. I changed my date to a random number and it sorts correctly so I just need to figure out the correct way to include the date.

Comment: Have you imported parse from date-fns library? Changing the numbers would be a solution if it was consistent. As you can see, it really depends on the numbers you provide which means that something is off. Either it sorts with any valid number or it does not work properly :-/. Take a look at the [parse](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/parse) and [format](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format) methods to understand how they work. Those links also contain useful examples on how they should be used.

Comment: @carlosV2 Yeah I have imported `parse`. Sorry to keep bothering you. I've spent half my day on this. Even when I copy and paste code from the docs I get errors. The only thing I can think of is using `new Date()` inside my object is giving me errors. `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Date]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: Let me add an answer as I can't share proper code on comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, there are a few issues with your code. I'll try to fix them by reducing your code to the simplest form possible and work our way up to what you expect.

Let's start the simplification by taking a look at the dates in the array's objects. For the first object, you have `format(new Date(), "2/13 2:09a")`. Given that you stated that the format is `M/dd h:mma`, I can easily convert this date into an ISO one: `2023/02/13 02:09:00`. The benefit of doing this is that this can be feed to `new Date()` very easily. If we apply those operations on both objects, we have the resulting array:

```js
const BlogTopic = [
  {
    title: "First Post",
    message: "test",
    author: "Dagger",
    date: new Date("2023/02/13 02:09:00"),
  },
  {
    title: "Second Post",
    message: "test",
    author: "Dagger",
    date: new Date("2023/02/13 03:48:00"),
  },
];
```

Ok, so far so good. Now, let's move to the next bit: sorting. Since the dates are now as a `Date` object, sorting is trivial. In fact you already provided the code for sorting, you just needed to reverse the operands:

```js
BlogTopic.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)
```

Please, note the following:

- I kept the parameters order as you had them `a, b`
- I reversed the substraction `b - a` instead of `a - b`
- Since the `date` parameter is already a Date object, we don't need to wrap it again

Great! Now we have an array properly sorted. The next step is about displaying this. As you saw, if you try `{new Date()}`, React will complaint because you are trying to display an object. What we need to do, therefore, is to turn this object into some string representation before giving it to React. For now, we will keep it simple and use the `toUTCString()` method (this is just for the sole purpose of simplifying your code, keep reading for your expected solution). So, now, we can do the following (again, keep in mind I'm simplifying your code for the sake of explaining all this, I know there are other parameters like `title` and `author`);

```js
BlogTopic.map(({ date }) => (
  <tr><td>{date.toUTCString()}</td></tr>
)}
```

Very well! So far we have managed to have an array with dates, sort it and display it so, the final piece to the puzzle is to use the format you need. As you pointed out, we will use `date-fns` to assist us with this. Among many other methods, this library has the following 2 that we will be using:

- [format](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format): Which takes a Date object and a pattern string and outputs an string with the date in the given format
- [parse](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/parse): Which takes a string with the date, a pattern declaring which format your date currently is and a Date object to provide defaults

The good thing about those functions is that they use the same format for the pattern string... that's handy!

Let's focus on the data input, this is your array. What you want here is to turn a string with a date in it (f.e. "2/13 2:09a") into a Date object which means that, from those functions, you need `parse`. Let's rewrite the array with this function:

```js
const BlogTopic = [
  {
    title: "First Post",
    message: "test",
    author: "Dagger",
    date: parse("2/13 2:09a", "M/dd h:mma", new Date()),
  },
  {
    title: "Second Post",
    message: "test",
    author: "Dagger",
    date: parse("2/13 3:48a", "M/dd h:mma", new Date()),
  },
];
```

The benefit here is that, because `parse` returns a Date object, any operations we do afterwards (like the sorting itself) can be kept as they are since we haven't changed the expected data type.

Finally, for displaying the date, we need a function that will take a Date object and turn it into a string, this is the job of the `format` function:

```js
BlogTopic.map(({ date }) => (
  <tr><td>{format(date, "M/dd h:mma")}</td></tr>
)}
```

And there you have it! If you have been following all along, you should now have a code that works the way you expected.

Comment: Thank you so much I greatly appreciate this. It does work but I had to change my `state` to `date: parse("2/17 3:48a", "M/dd h:mma", new Date()),` which works but only when I manually enter the date and time. Any ideas how to change it to current date and time? I'll update my post so it makes more sense.

Comment: If you want a Date object for the the current date and time you can simply do `new Date()`. No argument needed. Instantiating the Date object without arguments actually returns the current date and time and, since it is still a Date object, you can still use it with the rest of the sorting code discussed before.

Comment: I wanted to thank you again for putting in all this time and effort to help me out.